# Does the HTML5 Geolocation protocol work with just GPS connection enabled?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps

Here's a hypothesis:

- A simple web app based on the HTML5 Geolocation feature has a button "Get my location" that when clicked, will display the latitude and longitude of the client.
- The client accessing the app has GPS enabled, as well as a live data connection to the internet
- The client accesses the application, then once its loaded, the connection to the internet is severed; the client device GPS is still enabled and working

Question: will clicking the button still return the position of the client based on just the GPS input data? Or would an HTTP request need to precede that somehow?